# jQuery Countdown Timer "Jumping" up and down on IE8 & IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, countdown, countdowntimer

The countdown timer is Jumping up and down every time the clock ticks a new second.

The code is installed on:
http://www.gotmemories.com/content/article/124/place-order-from-quote-payment-order-form

```
<div id="defaultCountdown" class="hasCountdown"><span class="countdown_row countdown_show3"><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">0</span><br>Hours</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">0</span><br>Minutes</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">0</span><br>Seconds</span></span></div>
```

I am using the standard install of:
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Help greatly appreciated! I tried adding "max-height" css property and "height" but it didn't fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The jQuery was adding and removing a class every second called "countdown_rtl" to

`<div id="defaultCountdown" class="hasCountdown">`

The CSS was

```
.countdown_rtl {
      direction: rtl;
}
```

All I had to do was comment it out and it stopped bouncing around.

```
.countdown_rtl {
    /* direction: rtl; */
}
```

Not sure what that css is for but it seems to not work on IE and doesn't need it for anything else!
Hope this helps someone else.